# How to install plugins on Redmine hosted on Heroku.com

Tags: ruby, heroku, redmine, backlog

Just pushed redmine to the heroku platform, 
though I can't get the backlog-plugin to work, it works just fine locally.

I have pushed the local database to heroku aswwell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku's public directory is not writable. But a default Redmine assumes/requires so, as on start of the app server it copies static assets from the plugins (like images, javascripts, css) to the `public/plugin_assets` directory. On Heroku, this obviously fails. And as backlogs relies heavily on javascript, it's really noticeable.

A common work-around is to copy these assets manually before deploying. This can be done by running your config locally once and checking the copied assets into source control which is then deployed to Heroku.

Notice that `public/plugin_assets` is included into the default `.gitignore`, so you need to remove that from there obviously.